# Visual Studio macro to select the startup project

Tags: visual-studio, macros

In MSVC several operations (such as Menu: Build: Build ) are context sensitive to the currently selected Solution Project. However, that Project often changes if you've been navigating Solution Explorer.

I'd like to write a macro that find the project specified as the "startup project", and the selects it to make it active. I haven't found the appropriate DTE calls though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My primary goal was to build the startup project, which I have found a solution to:

```
Public Sub BuildStartupProject()
    Dim sb As SolutionBuild = DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild
    Dim projName As String = sb.StartupProjects(0)
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.Output")
    sb.BuildProject(sb.ActiveConfiguration.Name, projName, False)
End Sub
```

From the [Chromium project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/WindowsVisualStudioMacros#Only_build_startup_project).

Answer (score 1):

Here is somthing that should get you started, I have not verified if it will work when projects are nested inside a folder.

```
Sub SetStartupProjectasActive()
    Dim solutionName As String = DTE.Solution.Properties.Item("Name").Value
    Dim startupProject As String = DTE.Solution.Properties.Item("StartupProject").Value
    Dim fullItemName As String = String.Format("{0}\{1}", solutionName, startupProject)

    DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate()
    DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem(fullItemName).Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx, but the call to DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem fails, there is no "GetItem" on that object.