# Script to set up a new copy of a VS2012 solution

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012

Every time I get a copy of our project out of source control I have to:
- Change the startup projects
- Change the default startup page

I'd appreciate any hints on how to script this, and what files need to be modified.  Powershell preferred, but open to any solution...
Thanks.

Comment: What source control are you using? You shouldn't have to do that. What do you mean by "get a copy"? Are you actually creating a copy of what is in source control on your local box?

Comment: Looks like this question may help you

[Change start up project in visual studio][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301613/visual-studio-macro-to-select-the-startup-project

Comment: Hi, startup project is configured in user files (.*suo). This file is not sored in TFS. When you do get lastests version on your solution, the file is not affected and you will keep the same startup project.

Comment: Subversion for source control, but that doesn't matter.  When I check out a copy of trunk (or create a branch), the *.suo files are created when I first open the solution.  We have two startup projects, and a specific startup page.  Those are the things I would like to set via script.